# How to restrict file upload using allowTypes attribute of p:fileUpload in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I am new to `Primefaces`.

I need to restrict some file formats like `. pdf` and `. png`, other than those I need to allow to upload using `p:fileUpload` component in `Primefaces`.

I already tried some way like `allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(?!(pdf|png))$/"` but its not working.

Any idea to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|xlsm)$/i"
```

In that case files are allowed in the following formats: .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .pdf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm

It works for me.